# NodeJS readline: how to execute a function after all lines were read?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing an app to filter access files of a nodeJS api. The goal is to create another file with just the lines in a certain endpoint of the api. I can read all lines, find the ones I want but I'm having troubles to find when to save the new file. My code below:

```
var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('./log/access/' + fileToRead),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

rd.on('line', function (line) {

    if (line.search(methodToSearch) != -1) {
        console.log(line);
    }

});
```

I don't know the right event listener when all the lines are read.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it.

```
rd.on('close', function () {
    console.log('goodbye!');
    process.exit(0);
});
```